# Rails Routing Error on Email Confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, confirmation-email

I am new to rails and I am trying to add a email confirmation upon register. I currently get this error.

(**Bonus points** for **any** verbose and *easily understood* answer.)

### Routing Error

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"email_activations", :id=>false}

**config/routes.rb**

```
LootApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "password_resets/new"
  get "sessions/new"

  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :email_activations
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

**app/mailers/user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    def registration_confirmation(user)
        @user = user
        mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "registered", :from => "alain@private.com")
    end
end
```

**app/controllers/email_activations_controller.rb**

```
class EmailActivationsController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        @user = User.find_by_email_activation_token!(params[:id])
        @user.email_activation_token = true
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
    end
end
```

**app/views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.haml**

> Confirm your email address please!
>
> = edit_email_activation_url(@user.email_activation_token)

Comment: What url generates with edit_email_activation_url(@user.email_activation_token) ?

Comment: It doesn't even get that far. When I go to complete registration it just gives me that error immediately. No email is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources` keyword in rails routes is a magical keyword that creates 7 restful routes by default

`edit` is one of those

check these docs [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

edit expects to edit a record so requires a id to find the record for editing

in your case

you can just add a custom action in users controller

like

**in  UsersController**

```
  def accept_invitation
        @user = User.find_by_email_activation_token!(params[:token])
        @user.email_activation_token = true
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email has been verified."
    end
```

**in routes.rb**

```
   resources :users do
      collection do 
         get :accept_invitation
      end 
    end
```

**in app/views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.haml**

```
accept_invitation_users_url({:token=>@user.email_activation_token})
```

Check out how to add custom routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: for some reason that gives me this error 
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :id=>nil}