# Devise confirmation link gives me routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am finishing up simple application. I am using Devise gem as login and registration provider.

My problem: When user clicks his e-mail confirmation link I am getting routing error :

```
No route matches {:action=>"update_account", :controller=>"devise/users", :locale=>:ru}
```

My confirmation link looks like this:

```
www.mysite.com/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=dRRtTzVTy8gSF_D8FehF
```

In application layout I have user update form, where user can edit his details.

```
<%=  form_for(@user, :url => {  :action => "update_account",:controller =>"users" }, html: { "data-parsley-validate" => true, :id=>"user-edit-profile"},remote: true) do |f|    %> 

...
<%end%>
```

My routes:

```
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /lv|ee|ru/ do  

         devise_for :users,  :controllers => {:registrations=> "registrations"}

       resource :user do

            collection do
              post 'update_account'
             end               
            end
 end
```

UsersCotroller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


   before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :upvote, :downvote]
   before_action :authenticate_user!

  respond_to :html, :js


   def index
     @users = User.all
   end

    def show

    respond_with(@user)
  end

   def update_account

         @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user.attributes = user_params

     respond_to do |format|
             if @user.save(validate: false)
                   # sign_in :user, @user, bypass: true
              format.html 
              format.json
            else
             format.html { render action: 'edit' }
               format.json { render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity }
             end


          end   


  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    respond_with(@user)
  end

  def edit
  @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.' if @user.save
    respond_with(@user)
  end

  def update
    flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully updated.' if @user.update(user_params)
    respond_with(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
   respond_with(@user)
  end 


  def upvote
    @user.liked_by current_user
    flash[:notice] = 'Upvote added.' if @user.vote_registered?
     redirect_to @user
  end

  def downvote
    @user.downvote_from current_user
    flash[:notice] = 'Downvote added.' if @user.vote_registered?
     redirect_to @user
  end



  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

     def user_params
    # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
    params.required(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password,:name,:role, :email,:bypass_humanizer, :not_a_robot)
  end



end
```

**Routes:**

```
   new_user_session GET    (/:locale)/users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                  user_session POST   (/:locale)/users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
          destroy_user_session DELETE (/:locale)/users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                 user_password POST   (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
             new_user_password GET    (/:locale)/users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
            edit_user_password GET    (/:locale)/users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               PATCH  (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               PUT    (/:locale)/users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
      cancel_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/cancel(.:format)                     registrations#cancel {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
             user_registration POST   (/:locale)/users(.:format)                            registrations#create {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
         new_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/sign_up(.:format)                    registrations#new {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
        edit_user_registration GET    (/:locale)/users/edit(.:format)                       registrations#edit {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               PATCH  (/:locale)/users(.:format)                            registrations#update {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               PUT    (/:locale)/users(.:format)                            registrations#update {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               DELETE (/:locale)/users(.:format)                            registrations#destroy {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
             user_confirmation POST   (/:locale)/users/confirmation(.:format)               devise/confirmations#create {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
         new_user_confirmation GET    (/:locale)/users/confirmation/new(.:format)           devise/confirmations#new {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               GET    (/:locale)/users/confirmation(.:format)               devise/confirmations#show {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
           update_account_user POST   (/:locale)/user/update_account(.:format)              users#update_account {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                          user POST   (/:locale)/user(.:format)                             users#create {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                      new_user GET    (/:locale)/user/new(.:format)                         users#new {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                     edit_user GET    (/:locale)/user/edit(.:format)                        users#edit {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               GET    (/:locale)/user(.:format)                             users#show {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               PATCH  (/:locale)/user(.:format)                             users#update {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               PUT    (/:locale)/user(.:format)                             users#update {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                               DELETE (/:locale)/user(.:format)                             users#destroy {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                          help GET    (/:locale)/help(.:format)                             help#index {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
                         rules GET    (/:locale)/rules(.:format)                            rules#index {:locale=>/lv|ee|ru/}
```

I have tried to restart server but without success.

I couldn't find any similar question so I am creating new one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your email view?

Comment: Where's your `update_account` action is located? Do you actually have `UsersController`?

Comment: Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256004/rails-routing-error-on-email-confirmation

Comment: @AlexeyShein  Yes, I have user controller

Comment: Please, share its code here.

Comment: @AlexeyShein I did as you asked.

Comment: Ok, the controller looks fine, could you also share output of `rake routes` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a  simple solution as written below:

```
 <%=  form_for(@user, :url => "/user/update_account", html: { "data-parsley-validate" => true, :id=>"user-edit-profile"},remote: true) do |f|    %>
.....


<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is searching for action `update_account` under `:controller=>"devise/users"` because in routes you propeply have `devise_for :users` and at the same time you defined `users controller` which is inherit from `ApplicationController` all device controller are inherit from `Devise::ControllerName` so to solve that

- try changing controller name for `users` or
- try to define this function under `users controller` which inherit from `Devise`

Answer (score 1):

Change '*resource :user do*' to '*resource :users do*'

**Routes:**

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /lv|ee|ru/ do 
  devise_for :users,  :controllers => {:registrations=> "registrations"}

  resource :users do
    collection do
      post 'update_account'
    end               
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you didn't used `:confirmable` module of `devise` at your `app/models/user.rb` 
Please add this `:confirmable`. You can follow [this official](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users) link.